# Flex - Blaze DS Service retry

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

We have a flex application integrated with java-spring using BlazeDS. The application provides the user a JMS interaction screen where the user has to enter parameters like url and queue details and a message will be posted on to that queue.
The problem is that whenever the server layer (java) takes time to respond, somehow another request gets sent to the server.

The log looks like this:

2011-10-11 03:17:19 INFO [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - JanusFilter.processJanusPrincipal -> janusPrincipal====D
2011-10-11 03:17:19 INFO [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - TraceLoggerUtil.logBefore -> Start of JMSClientServiceImpl.sendJMSMessage
2011-10-11 03:17:19 INFO [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - JMSClientServiceImpl.sendJMSMessage -> :: Sending JMS message
2011-10-11 03:22:19 INFO [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - JanusFilter.processJanusPrincipal -> janusPrincipal====D
2011-10-11 03:22:19 INFO [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - TraceLoggerUtil.logBefore -> Start of JMSClientServiceImpl.sendJMSMessage
2011-10-11 03:22:19 INFO [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] - JMSClientServiceImpl.sendJMSMessage -> :: Sending JMS message

Is there some sort of property in Flex's Remote Object or BlazeDS that makes this retry possible?
Notice there is an interval of 5 mins.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem in our QA environment. We have an Apache web server configured beside weblogic servers. The request goes to Apache webserver first, where the session timeout is set as 5 minutes.

So for every 5 minutes,if the server is busy with current request, the request is resend again. To fix this, change the WLIOTimeoutSecs paratemter in apache config to more than 300(default).

Hope this helps..